# avoid DNSMASQ making changes in resolv.conf

Tags: dnsmasq

not able to find a workaround for the dnsmasq to not make changes in /etc/resolv.conf file.

editing the init.d/dnsmasq file is not a full option as not on all ubuntu version dnsmasq runs through init.d

hope you can help !

Comment: Found an interesting file /etc/resolvconf/update.d/dnsmasq .  As for me , I've set my dns through /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf, now no matter what , nm-tool reports that i use those dns servers that i specified. Want me to post it as an answer ?

Comment: if you could describe a bit more throughout i would be grateful. 

as an answer would be great !

Comment: i came to find that on those versions of dnsmasq without the  daemon in init.d , there is no such file -- /etc/resolvconf/update.d/dnsmasq

this is a file the daemon in init.d generates.


i am looking for a workaround in these specific folders which remain no matter dnsmasq and ubuntu version -- /etc/dnsmasq.conf or  or /etc/default/dnsmasq

Answer (score 1):

Problem is because Network Manager uses dynamically your `/etc/resolv.conf` with `dnsmasq`

Solution for you to change way how to resolve names. Try following

In `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` comment out the `dns=dnsmasq`

`sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
 [main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
#dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=00:22:64:4E:6F:70,

[ifupdown]
managed=fals
```

and restart the NM service

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

With this `/etc/resolv.conf` is no longer dependant on `resolvconf` package and is updated based on the DNS entries of each connection in the Network Manager

Also you can add nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf`. If you not set dns in NM per connection this will be used

`sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

*Edit One*

Stop the service `resolvconf`

```
sudo service resolvconf stop
```

disable it

```
update-rc.d resolvconf disable
```

disable `resolvconf` to overwrite `resolv.conf`

create `/etc/init/resolvconf.override` with single line `manual`

```
echo 'manual' | sudo tee /etc/init/resolvconf.override
```

remove symbolic link `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
rm /etc/resolv.conf
```

create `resolv.conf` with static dns entry

```
echo "namserver x.x.x.x." > /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: i don't have such file 

/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

Comment: should i install network manager ??

Comment: network manager does not help. commenting out the conf file of network manager file does nothing for me.

the init.d of dnsmasq still edits the resolv.conf file and uses the echo-ed nameserver and the dns servers of the IPv6 protocol

Comment: You have my `edit one` in answer

Comment: is there maybe an option i can add in /etc/dnsmasq.conf  or 
/etc/dnsmasq.d or /etc/default/dnsmasq  than does the same thing ?

Comment: No,  you can not create sonething.config and read DNS config from there. Resolv  lib look  `/etc/host.conf` for order and `/etc/hosts` for local host  Default order is `order hosts,bind` If you dont have entry for specific address in `/etc/hosts` PC will ask `bind->/etc/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not solve your problem, but I was having a similar problem where dnsmasq (well, actually the combo of dnsmasq and resolvconf) was rewriting my /etc/resolv.conf file and ignoring the dns-nameservers options that I set in /etc/network/interfaces.

What the problem turned out to be was that resolvconf would call dnsmasq to update the nameserver entries in resolv.conf, and then it seems that it would quit after that.

I got it to keep the dns-nameservers entries from /etc/network/interfaces by moving my interface (`p+([0-9])p+([0-9])?(_+([0-9]))*` in my case) to before the "lo.dnsmasq" entry in /etc/resolvconf/interface-order. So now instead of getting "nameserver 127.0.0.1" as the first, last, and only nameserver entry in /etc/resolv.conf, I get

`nameserver <ipaddr.frometc.network.interfaces>
nameserver <another.frometc.network.interfaces>
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search <domains from /etc/network/interfaces>`

So now it seems that resolvconf runs, checks the interface order, and adds the entries from /etc/network/interfaces corresponding to the entries above "lo.dnsmasq", then calls a dnsmasq process to add those to the file, but that somehow works not quite right and it ignores any interfaces after that.

When I was trying to figure this out I searched, to no avail, about why dnsmasq was ignoring /etc/network/interfaces. (I was certain that dnsmasq was involved because this happened shortly after I installed dnsmasq) I am not sure if that solves your problem, but to me it seemed a little bit cleaner than just removing resolvconf.

Comment: This got me half-way to a solution however my `dns-nameservers` directive in my /etc/network/interfaces for a static ip bridge seemed to be completely ignored for reasons I don't know.  I was only able to get going after commenting out `dns-nameservers` and adding something like this: `post-up echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /var/run/resolvconf/interfaces/br0MANUAL.inet && /usr/sbin/resolvconf -u`.  I'm not entirely happy with these two kludges (interface-order edits and the post-up edit) and would certainly entertain cleaner alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting chattr to immutable.

```
chattr +i /path/to/filename
```

To remove immutable to allow changes again change the flag on the file.

```
chattr -i /path/to/filename
```